How to scroll to a specific element in a dynamically loaded list <ul> using Python and SeleniumBase/ Selenium?
I have an unordered list element (<ul):
<ul><li><li>...

with over 50 list items (<li), but only the first 10 are loaded initially. I need to scroll using SeleniumBase, but if you know how it works using selenium it can maybe help me too, to the 45th item when the item isn't loaded at first. for example my XPath is:
"//ul[@title=test']//li[@title='45']"

but I can't find it since it's not loaded initially.
How can I scroll to this item and ensure it's loaded before interacting with it?
I tried to scroll to the 10th, and then to the 20th and so on, but the code didnt scroll to those elements, and I didn't get any error message.
I tried it using this line:
self.scroll_to_element('//ul[@title="test]//li[@title="10"]')
self.scroll_to_element('//ul[@title="test]//li[@title="20"]')

I tried to scroll till the end of the (<ul) using scroll_to_bottom() but it scroll to the end of the page and not the end of the list element.
Any help would be appreciated!

Can you share what you have tried? Without that, I can't help you properly.

Like I wrote:
I tried to scroll to the 10th element using: scroll_to_element  to the 10th  for the other elements to be loaded but it didnt work, it didnt loaded the other elements thus I couldnt continue the scrolling.
I tried to scroll to the end using: scroll_to_bottom of the list but it didnt work as well, it scroll me to the end of the page and not to the end of the list.

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

Thanks @JeffC, I added the lines of code I used and the results I got.
About the html I gave an example of the html line I have:
ul[@title='test'] this is the list I have.

import selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def existOrNot(Xpath):
    page =driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    if soup.find(Xpath):
        return(True)
    else: 
        return (False)


Xpath= soup.find("ul", title='test').find("li",title='45')
while not existOrNot(Xpath):
   driver.send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(3)

